# Splice 2 PDF pages into one with Python

Tags: python, pdf-generation

I'm trying to write a novel and I am trying to print out my own book prototypes.

I have a PDF of the book. Now I want to merge the pages so that I can print it double-sided, fold it in half, and staple it like a boss.

The problem I need to solve is how to splice 2 pages together with a left and right side. I looked at PyPDF2 and its `mergePage` function, but it only superimposes one page onto another. The new generated page will be twice the width of the original pages, one page superimposed on the left, and one page superimposed on the right.

Thank you for your time in looking at this!

Comment: You might want to take a look at reportlab (http://www.reportlab.com/software/opensource/). It's got a ton of advanced features and I've used it for PDF generation before, but not sure if it can edit existing PDFs.

Comment: Booklet printing is something most PDF readers should already have; but with pypdf, you can use [mergeTranslatedPage()](http://sourcecodebrowser.com/python-pypdf/1.13/classpy_pdf_1_1pdf_1_1_page_object.html#adf7ba580c6d63b621d93c1638d28d37f) to do this as well.

Answer (score 0):

Turns that Adobe's reader has a "Booklet" option in the printing options. Worked out nicely.